# Trying to move 1 object with arrow keys and another one with wasd

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D game and I want to move a left block with the arrow keys and a right block with A and D, but I can only make one move with WASD or the arrow keys, I am very new to C# and Unity.

I've tried making 2 'horizontals', by making one A and D and the other one with left arrow and right arrow key in Project Settings,  but that doesn't seem to work, thanks so much :*)

This is for player 1

```
    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal1"), 0f);
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
```

And player 2 is the same code, just with ("Horizontal2")

Comment: Try using [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Input.GetKey(KeyCode)` to read players' input. Also, assign the KeyCode in the inspector for each player.

Here is a sample code that might be help:

```
public KeyCode leftKey  = KeyCode.A; // Change to KeyCode.LeftArrow in inspector
public KeyCode rightKey = KeyCode.D;
public float   speed = 1.0f;

private Vector2 _moveVelocity;
private RigidBody2D _rigidBody;

private void Start()
{
    _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector2 moveInput = Vector2.zero;
    if(Input.GetKey(leftKey))
    {
        moveInput = Vector2.left;
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(rightKey))
    {
        moveInput = Vector2.right;
    }

    _moveVelocity = moveInput * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    _rigidBody.velocity = _moveVelocity;

}
```